# vba skip popup message box in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I’m a beginner and desperately seeking for help. I would kindly request your support and apologize in advance for the poor wording and eventual lack of info (again, I’m a rookie). I’m building an Excel macro to fill in a (private) webpage and after filling in the requested data, I’m also able to call the javascript function that submits the data/form. However, it appears a “Message from webpage” that I’m unable to confirm (always "ok"/enter) or simple skip. The Macro just stops and I can’t do anything without clicking manually in the “ok” button. I’ve spend several hours searching and trying different solutions but nothing seems to work, probably due to my poor skills. Hereunder I send the code that is beating me hard (hope is enough). Looking forward for your help

MY CODE

```
DIM HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

' Submits data but gets stuck in the popup message box
HTMLdoc.all.Item
Call HTMLdoc.parentWindow.execScript("licitarLeilao();", "JScript")
```

WEBPAGE

```
...
function licitarLeilao(){
    var ultimaLicitacao = document.getElementById('ultimaLicitacao').value;
    var valorLicitar = document.getElementById('valorLicitar').value;

    if(ultimaLicitacao == ' -- '){
        ultimaLicitacao = document.getElementById('valorBase').value;
    }

    var racio = toNum(valorLicitar) / toNum(ultimaLicitacao);

    if (racio < 1.5) {
        if(!confirm('Confirma o valor de licitação (' + valorLicitar +' eur.) do leilão?')){
            return false;
        }   
    }
    else {  
        if(!confirm('ATENÇÃO!! O valor de licitação é muito superior à última licitação. \n\n Confirma o valor de licitação (' + valorLicitar +' eur.) do leilão?')){
            return false;
        }
    }   

    var flow = document.getElementById('flow');
    flow.value = '8';

    document.formulario.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try overwriting `window.confirm` with a different functionality:

```
With HTMLdoc.parentWindow
    .execScript "window.confirm = function(){return true;};", "JScript"
    .execScript "licitarLeilao();", "JScript"
End With
```

In a test page that worked OK for me.

**NOTE**: if there's any other code on the web page which uses `confirm` then the functionality of that code may be impacted.

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly… I can’t assess the complexity of the solution (seems simple what is great), but I can tell you that you’ve helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time. Many thanks