# VBA code to click OK on Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, vba

I'm automating a VBA script to enter info on a webpage. I'm doing great until I get to this section of the code on the webpage:

```
   var message = "You must read and accept these terms .\n\n";
   if(index < 10)

   var response = confirm(message);

   if (response==true) {frm.h_index.value = index; frm.submit(); return true;}
   else return false;
```

I can execute a `.Click` function on the original webpage which then causes this popup to run. From here, my code can't do anything until I manually click OK on the Javascript popup. I've searched all I can, and still not sure how to handle this.

How can I programmatically dismiss that Javascript popup?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064846/vba-skip-popup-message-box-in-webpage

Answer (score 0):

Popup window needs to be searched first and you have to send .click to that particular IE object. Please find the sample function and Sub which you can use. In following code, you need to send .click to iePopup object once it is found.

```
'Add references: Microsoft Internet Controls & Microsoft HTML Object Library
Sub TestURLmatch()
Dim ie As Object
Dim sMatch As String

'URL needs to be changed in next line
sMatch = "http://www.google.com"

On Error Resume Next
Set iePopup = GetIEatURL(sMatch & "*")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not iePopup Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Found webpage at " & iePopup.LocationURL
End If
End Sub

Function GetIEatURL(sMatch As String) As Object
Dim ie As Object, oShApp As Object, oWin As Object
Set oShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each oWin In oShApp.Windows
    If TypeName(oWin.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        Set ie = oWin
        If LCase(ie.LocationURL) Like LCase(sMatch) Then
            Set GetIEatURL = ie
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
Set oShApp = Nothing
Set oWin = Nothing

End Function
```